# Replace all ocurrence of something with only one

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How to replace all ocurrences of `<p>[gallery ids=""]</p>` if they exist with only one?

```
  $string = "/\<p\>\[gallery ids=\"\"\]\<\/p\>/";
  $content = "asdfsdfdsafasdfaasfddsaf <p>[gallery ids=""]</p><p>[gallery ids=""]</p><p>[gallery ids=""]</p>";
  if (preg_match_all($string, $content, $matches)) {

  }
```

The `$content` should be `asdfsdfdsafasdfaasfddsaf <p>[gallery ids=""]</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$content = 'asdfsdfdsafasdfaasfddsaf <p>[gallery ids=""]</p><p>[gallery ids=""]</p><p>[gallery ids=""]</p>';
$content = preg_replace("/(<p>\[gallery ids=\"\"\]<\/p>){2,}/", "$1", $content);

print_r($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping way to many things, you need to find the matter with a quantifier, `{1,}`in this case: between 1 and unlimited times.

Also add a `g` global modifier in case you've got newlines in your content.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<p>\[gallery ids=""\]<\/p>){1,}/g', '$1', $content);
```